# Correct way co create inner columns inside a row

Tags: tables

I'm trying to create a table wich has two columns for all rows except one, the code I'm using is this

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model Parameters} \\ \midrule
    Hidden layers & 1 & 2 \\
    Units in hidden layer & \multicolumn{2}{c}{100-1000} \\
    Input Scaling & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.5-1.0} \\ 
    Spectral Radius & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.1-0.99} \\
    Leaky & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.1-1.0} \\
    Connectivity Input & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\approx units$} \\
    Connectivity Recurrent & \multicolumn{2}{c}{10} \\
    Learning rate & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.01, 0.001, 0.0001}\\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

But as you can see from the picture, the top row and the hidden layer rows are not centered. What's the correct way to center the text?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Please clarify how the table *should* look like. E.g., should the right-hand cells in the row that starts with "Hidden layers" have the same widths?

Comment: To get "Model Parameters" centered across all rows, just change `\multicolumn{2}{c}{Model Parameters}` to `\multicolumn{3}{c}{Model Parameters}`.

Comment: How about [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIqpR.png)?

Answer (score 6):

For this answer, I have assumed that the "1" and "2" cells in the "hidden layers" row should be equally wide. If this assumption is correct, the following answer may be of interest to you. It employs an "inner" `tabular` environment and uses the `\widthof` macro of the `calc` package to determine the usable widths of the two otherwise-hidden cells.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath} \useosf % optional: Palatino-clone fonts
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{calc}  % for \widthof macro
\usepackage{array} % for 'w' column type
\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{(\widthof{0.01, 0.001, 0.0001}-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth)/2}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c} % start the outer 'tabular' env.
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model Parameters} \\ 
    \midrule
    Hidden layers & 
        %% start the inner 'tabular' environment
        \begin{tabular}{ @{} wc{\mylen} | wc{\mylen}@{} } 
           1 & 2 
       \end{tabular} \\
    Units in hidden layer  & 100--1000 \\
    Input Scaling          & 0.5--1.0  \\ 
    Spectral Radius        & 0.1--0.99 \\
    Leaky                  & 0.1--1.0 \\
    Connectivity Input     & $\approx \mathit{units}$ \\
    Connectivity Recurrent & 10 \\
    Learning rate          & 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for all. Especially for you in having identified the correct font.

Answer (score 5):

If I properly understand your needs...

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
    \toprule
 %   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model Parameters} \\ \midrule
   \multicolumn{3}{c}{Model Parameters} \\ \midrule
    Hidden layers & 1 & 2 \\
    Units in hidden layer & \multicolumn{2}{c}{100-1000} \\
    Input Scaling & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.5-1.0} \\ 
    Spectral Radius & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.1-0.99} \\
    Leaky & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.1-1.0} \\
    Connectivity Input & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\approx units$} \\
    Connectivity Recurrent & \multicolumn{2}{c}{10} \\
    Learning rate & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.01, 0.001, 0.0001}\\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    
Or rather

   \begin{tabular}{c|c}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model Parameters} \\ \midrule
 
    Hidden layers & 1  \\ %2 seems to be only  a marker
    Units in hidden layer & {100-1000} \\
    Input Scaling &{0.5-1.0} \\ 
    Spectral Radius & {0.1-0.99} \\
    Leaky & {0.1-1.0} \\
    Connectivity Input & {$\approx units$} \\
    Connectivity Recurrent & {10} \\
    Learning rate & {0.01, 0.001, 0.0001}\\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular} 
    
\end{document}
```

The result of the compilation is obvious, so I have omitted a picture.

For the future: please put here a compilable document, starting from `\documentclass` and so on. Now I am only guessing that you are using `booktabs` package.